# Who REALLY killed Derek?

Tags: logical-deduction

6 people shared a building in London - Lisa the teacher, Caroline the maid, Alice the businesswoman, Thomas the London Underground driver, Derek the coffee-shop owner, and Michael the prison guard.

One day, they moved to New York, retaining their original jobs.

They very much enjoyed the new scenery, as well as all the sights. They had lived in near bliss in their new home for about 3 weeks.

However, one Sunday, Derek was killed! The police rushed over when Lisa found the body after coming home.

The coroner put the time of death around 10 am, the murder weapon being a gun, sealed in a safe for protection. Only the roommates knew the code.

The police took statements from each of the roommates.

Lisa said she was teaching a class.
Caroline said she was getting the mail.
Alice said she was in a meeting.
Thomas said he was running the Victoria line.
Michael said he was called to the prison for a routine checkup.

Immediately they arrested Caroline, since there is no mail on Sundays.

But soon after, they found out there WAS mail today - a package had arrived for Sunday delivery.

So if Caroline didn't kill Derek, **then who did**?

NOTE: Derek didn't commit suicide.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think it was

> Thomas

Because

> The Victoria Line isn't in NY

Comment: It is curious that he would somehow keep his job, as a driver, for 3 weeks while living 3,459 miles away.  Unless, of course, they moved to Lincolnshire (Still 130m away).

Comment: He's just got really long arms.

Comment: There are [three New Yorks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_York_(disambiguation)) in England, didn't know that!

Comment: @Narmer hm, didn't think of that. Wouldn't the bobbies show up instead of the police? Plus - they have a gun.

Comment: This is the right answer, although I'll keep @Narmer's note in mind next time I make one of these :)

Comment: @Raystafarian On the plus, I actually loled

Comment: Ah, so here's what really happened, then:  Gubznf, orvat hanoyr gb cresbez uvf wbo qhr gb qvfgnapr, fgnegrq gb unir zbarl vffhrf. Ur tbg va, onq, jvgu n ybna funex. Uvf ebbzzngrf, orvat boyvivbhf gb gur snpg gung ur pbhyqa'g jbex fb sne njnl, qvqa'g abgvpr. Ur orpnzr qrcerffrq naq wbvarq n perj, eboovat onaxf. Bar qnl, gurl eboorq n onax npebff sebz Qrerx'f pbssrr fubc naq ur jvgarffrq vg. Gubznf'f perj pbreprq uvz vagb xvyyvat Qrerx gb cerirag uvz sebz grfgvslvat

Comment: Hey, they can operate drones in Afghanistan from a remote station in Indiana.  Surely that's more complicated than operating a subway train remotely.

Comment: Hahahah  Yeah, well - he was a driver, not an operator. :P

Comment: @ASCIIThenANSI How do you rule out the other suspects?

Comment: @jpmc26 I didn't. I picked some random jobs, one of which didn't make sense in New York. I didn't think it would actually go this far.

Answer (score 4):

> Michael

must also have been lying.

> I'm pretty sure you need a US background check to work as a prison guard in New York, which takes more than 3 weeks.

Comment: The background check could have started before they moved.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's

> Lisa

because you do not usually teach a class on a Sunday.

Comment: Maybe it was sunday school

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is

> Alice because normal business people don't work on Sunday

Comment: Even in a city such as NY?